# How to install XML::Twig for Windows XP

Tags: activeperl, xml-twig

I tried installing `XML::Twig` using ppm and also tried manually by adding twig.pm files in the perl/lib folder, also tried using Nmake but got an error

> "NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\Documents'  Stop."

How do I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I've found, is to start off with [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), which includes pre-build `XML::Twig` and `XML::LibXML`

I know that isn't quite what you asked - but I found it a perpetual nuisance to get the XML library dependencies installed, so this is the approach I adopted.